# how to add first waiting list passenger to the seat list after someone cancelled his seat in c#?

Tags: c#

> I am working on an airline reservation project by using C# windows form. Click “Cancel” to delete the passenger’s booking .If the waiting list is not empty, remove the first person from the list and give her/him the newly vacated seat. Any idea? 
>   Here is my code:>

```
private void deleteClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // enter name and validate it
            //validate input
            row = rowListBox.GetItemText(rowListBox.SelectedItem);
            column = seatListBox.GetItemText(seatListBox.SelectedItem);
            if (row.Equals(""))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Row selection is needed", "Error",
                 MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                return;
            }
            if (column.Equals(""))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Seat selection is needed", "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                return;
            }

            // delete passenger from the list
            rowNumber = int.Parse(row);

            for (int r = 0; r < 5; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
                {
                    if (c == 0)
                    {
                        col = "A";
                    }
                    else if (c == 1)
                    {
                        col = "B";
                    }
                    else if (c == 2)
                    {
                        col = "C";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        col = "D";
                    }

                    if (rowNumber == r + 1 && column == col && seating[r, c] == null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Seat is not taken. Please select a different seat", "Seat Taken",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                    else if (rowNumber == r + 1 && column == col && seating[r, c] != null)
                    {
                        seating[r, c] = "";
                        isTaken[r, c] = false;
                        count--;
                        output += (r + 1) + col + "-" + seating[r, c] + "\n";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isTaken[r, c] = false;
                        output += (r + 1) + col + "-" + "\n";
                    }

                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need two for loops? You have an array seating[r, c] and you know what the row and column number are.  Not need to go through a loop.

Comment: you can use Queue(FIFO) data structure for the waiting list . When you dequeue you will get always the person who has waited the most. Hope this help or I misunderstood you question.

Comment: Well I don't see where you are storing any passenger stuff, but you can either with LINQ do a .First() after an orderby if needed, or if you are using something else you can take the Index[0], or you can take the first in a list. Without seeing more its hard to say exactly what you can do.